# How to airdrop tokens to multiple addresses in one transaction

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to host an airdrop but sending the tokens individually to thousands of people would take forever. Is there a way to do it in one transaction with multiple recipients.

If so, could you please provide me with some code.

Thanks

Comment: Am adding comment here to help people trying to do via mist after created their token to refer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/31332/20357

Comment: This changes a lot if you mean sending ether or sending ERC20 tokens.

Answer (score 5):

You are quite discouraged to use the *sending* pattern, especially if you want to send/transfer funds (ether/tokens etc.) to thousands of people as you mentioned. This way you can easily get self-pwned by running out of gas, for instance. Have a look at [this](https://ethereum.karalabe.com/talks/2016-hackethon.html#7) (and the next slide). Another problem with the sending pattern is that you should have in mind that there is no guarantee that the `.send()` (or `.transfer()`) function will succeed. You should be always prepared for such edge cases in your smart contract code, i.e. bail out, work arounds etc. Perfect example for this is the [KingOfTheEtherThrone](http://www.kingoftheether.com/postmortem.html) 'hack'.

Therefore you should use the withdrawal pattern, where your users/partners will withdraw their funds, you should not get involved sending funds around. The withdrawal pattern is greatly explained [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-from-contracts).

Comment: This answer applies to send( ) of ether, the question was about sending tokens, which is not about sending anything actually but invoking transfer() in a ERC20 contract

Comment: Made some edit to reflect your just comment! Thanks!

Comment: there is a lot of things that can go wrong with this approach. For example, if a recipient is smart contract that cannot receive Ether, the JavaScript side has to dry-run and pre-validate all addresses. I'd recommend trying https://multisender.app because it does all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

On chain you would have to use a contract with something like a sendToMany function:

```
function sendToMany(address[] recipients) {
for(uint i = 0; i< recipients.length; i++){
     i.send(msg.value/recipients.length);
     }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to calculate gas ahead of time so you don't exceed the gas limit. Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4fija2/is_this_true_ethereum_does_not_allow_multiple/

Comment: How to send token to 7000 address in single transaction? this will give out of gas error . Even if i want user to withdraw their fund I have to store their fund in contract which will also run out of gas if i want to store for 7000 address?

I am trying to distribute fund here on a single transaction. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-script-an-automatic-token-airdrop-for-40k-subscribers-e40c8b1a02c6) gives a good solution.

- Have all your addesses in a CSV file (remove blanks or erroneous addresses first)
- Make an `airdropTokens(address[] addresses, value)` function in your token contract that transfers `value` tokens to each address with a `for` loop.
- Write a scipt to call the function the entries of your CSV file. The article recommends to slice your data, calling the function by batches of 80 (in his example). Calling a function with a very large array might be inefficient.

The article gives more detail but basically that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this open-source tool - http://bulktokensending.online
It allows generating ETH addresses also. The source is here https://github.com/bulktokensending/bulktokensending