# What is the format for sending erc20 token to multiple address?

Tags: erc-20

Code

> contract ERC20 {   function transfer(address _recipient, uint256
>   _value) public returns (bool success); }
>
> contract Airdrop {   function drop(ERC20 token, address[] recipients,
>   uint256[] values) public {
>       for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
>         token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
>       }   } }

How to use.
Please can you tell me what is the format i have to put address and token value to send. I have tried many formats but not worked.
token send to multiple addresses in one transaction.

Please can you tell me what is the format i have to put address and token value. I have tried many formats but not worked.

Please

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a multisend function in the [standard ERC20 interface](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard#The_ERC20_Token_Standard_Interface). If you're using a variation of ERC20, please tell us more about it. For implementation of a multisend function check out [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31971/airdropping-erc20-tokens-to-multiple-addresses-in-a-single-transaction) and [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40228/best-practice-for-airdrops-and-gas-usage).

Comment: Thanks for replying sfmiller940.  sfmiller94    



Code
contract ERC20 {
  function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
}

contract Airdrop {
  function drop(ERC20 token, address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
      token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
    }
  }
}


How to use.
Please can you tell me what is the format i have to put address and token value to send. I have tried many formats but not worked.

Comment: How are you calling the Airdrop function? From inside the contract or externally with JavaScript, etc.? Can You share that code?

Comment: Test Coin in this contract https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x515dea727d31cb64946c2139d04d91b8781d671a



Bulk transfer code deployed in this contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9fea6ed7edcb51f589265cb1f6613dc6e878f7c9#code

Need to transfer Test coin using the bulk transfer.

I have tried using myetherwallet.com for bulk transfer.

Comment: There's alot going on here... But when BulkTransfer.bulkTransfer() calls testcoinerc20.transfer(), the address msg.sender in testcoinerc20.transfer() is the address of the contract BulkTransfer. The address that you use to call BulkTransfer.bulkTransfer() is tx.origin. Does the BulkTransfer contract have a balance in testcoinerc20? If not, then you might want to use [tx.origin instead of msg.sender](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin) in testcoinerc20.transfer() or use another approach.

Comment: ... or use testcoinerc20.transfer() to transfer the necessary balance to BulkTransfer's address before using bulktransfer.

Comment: Yes I just transferred 455,555 TEST to BulkTransfer contract.
 https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x515dea727d31cb64946c2139d04d91b8781d671a?a=0x9fea6ed7edcb51f589265cb1f6613dc6e878f7c9   And tried to do bulk transfer but not working...

Comment: Maybe try using "[interface](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#interfaces)" instead of "contract" to declare BulkTransfer.IERC20?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but I would also use the same name "testcoinerc20" instead of "IERC20". I think names like that can get hashed in somewhere important.

Comment: No its not working.. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd7c484102de1e79e82b33ab5baaba8cd084b0f02#code

Comment: Did you see my first comment about using "[interface](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#interfaces)" instead of an [abstract contract](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#abstract-contracts)?