# Airdrop generated token to multi address by contract failed

Tags: airdrop

Below is my operation steps：

1. I create a token  0x260c4b1cd063599949b530454d22081b94c170ef whose owner is 0xAbA5862c54254750b2EFe8BEB72f528DAF73547F
   You can check this token's code by https://etherscan.io/address/0x260c4b1cd063599949b530454d22081b94c170ef#code
   compile version is : 0.4.22+commit.4cb486ee.Emscripten.clang
2. then publish a contract using @Rajesh code [Unable to check Airdropped Tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31185/unable-to-check-airdropped-tokens/31332#31332) , the contract address is https://etherscan.io/address/0x7449605903e5e851f34d78accbe78e4c54dbab45 whose owner is also 0xAbA5862c54254750b2EFe8BEB72f528DAF73547F same as above token, compile version is also 0.4.22+commit.4cb486ee.Emscripten.clang
3. I sent some token to above contract from owner , tx is https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6e8091e585b63c62103ebb1fbc40d90c5604f5b6459b7ddd4eecf6794a183b7b
4. with parity I call transfer by below bash command

> owner=0xAbA5862c54254750b2EFe8BEB72f528DAF73547F 
>   to=0x7449605903e5e851f34d78accbe78e4c54dbab45 methodid=0xad8733ca
>   array_0=0000000000000000000000008138ee2d269b1d85a81df6dd925f1f83d1ffa7cf
>   array_1=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
>   data=${methodid}${array_0}${array_1}
>   curl  -X POST -H 'content-type:
>   application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0","method":
>   "personal_sendTransaction","params": [{"from":
>   "'"$owner"'","to":"'"$to"'","data": "'"$data"'"},"'"$PASS"'"],"id":
>   1}' http://127.0.0.1:$port

5. transaction done well, but no any token is transfered , transactions is https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0dbc844714ae2d3b3310ee9b7efac6f930160e55559b1b634a59bdc4f33bef1d
   [image]

Please help me to check , thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is arrays are dynamic so they are encoded differently that static types like uint256. See the [Solidity ABI specs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html) for the details.

In your case it should be something like this:

```
d8b66ae1 // method's signature

// offset dests array
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040  
// offset values array
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080

// dests array
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001  // array length
0000000000000000000000008138ee2d269b1d85a81df6dd925f1f83d1ffa7cf  // array elements follow

// values array
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001  // length
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001  // elements
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try, thank you again

Comment: It work well now according to your suggestion , thanks you very much